# How can I extract a PHP string from this sub-array?

Tags: php, bigcommerce, arrays

The array I am looking at is this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Bigcommerce\Api\Resources\ProductCustomField Object
            (
                [ignoreOnCreate:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => id
                        [1] => product_id
                    )

                [ignoreOnUpdate:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => id
                        [1] => product_id
                    )

                [fields:protected] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 17
                        [product_id] => 3232
                        [name] => Artist
                        [text] => Test
                    )

                [id:protected] => 17
                [ignoreIfZero:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I want to check to see if 'Artist' exists in a php conditional statement.  But I don't know how to turn 'Artist' into a string.

UPDATED:
I did not find understand how to extract that value into a string, but I got what I was looking for using the method related to the bigcommerce api:

```
$customs = Bigcommerce::getProductCustomFields($product->id);
foreach($customs as $custom) {
if($custom->name == 'Artist'): // do something 
endif;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to access the `ProductCustomField` protected `$fields` property, like via a getter (eg `$obj->getFields()`)?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I was not able to find clear documentation, but I think this should look up the customfields... Bigcommerce::getProductCustomFields($product->id);
But I still don't know how to access it from that.

Comment: Would you pls add var_export($yourArray) so it will be easier for us to use it and run for testing?

Comment: array ( 0 => array ( 0 => Bigcommerce\Api\Resources\ProductCustomField::__set_state(array( 'ignoreOnCreate' => array ( 0 => 'id', 1 => 'product_id', ), 'ignoreOnUpdate' => array ( 0 => 'id', 1 => 'product_id', ), 'fields' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'id' => 17, 'product_id' => 3232, 'name' => 'Artist', 'text' => 'Test', )), 'id' => 17, 'ignoreIfZero' => array ( ), )), ), )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looking at the [source](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/blob/master/src/Bigcommerce/Api/Resource.php), it seems you should be able to use the magic `__get` method. Try

```
$array[0][0]->name == 'Artist'
```

Comment: I hadn't looked at that.  It's probably easier to do with those functions.  But I'm still confused as to what the $field would be for the custom value I created for the product (which is the artist name.)

Answer (score 0):

The value of the custom field would be stored in the "text" resource for that custom field.

See the following link where you can see the 4 properties of a custom field.
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/custom_fields